# compare times with hundredths in php

Tags: php, strtotime, milliseconds

I try to compare two swim times in php. They are like `HH:MM:SS.XX` (`XX` are hundreths). I get them as string and i want to find out which swimmer is faster. I tryed to convert them using `strtotime()`. It works with hours, minutes and seconds but it ignores hundreths. Here is my code for better explanation:

```
$novy = strtotime($input1); 
$stary = strtotime($input2);
if($novy < $stary){
   //change old(stary) to new(novy)
}
```

If `$input1` is `00:02:14.31` and `$input2` is `00:02:14.3`2 both `$novy` and `$stary` are `1392850934`.
I read some solution to similar problem in javascript but I can`t use it, this must be server-side. 
Thank you for help.

Comment: **[MICROTIME](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php)** may help ? like     $novy = strtotime($input1,microtime());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is really `HH:MM:SS.XX` (ie: with leading 0's), you can just sort them alphabetically:

```
<?php
$input1 = '00:02:14.31';
$input2 = '00:02:14.32';
if ($input1 < $input2) {
    echo "1 faster\n";
} else {
    echo "2 faster\n";
}
```

It prints `1 faster`

Comment: This works fine, but i m not sure that it will work always. I m not sure if is best idea to compare numeric information as string.

Comment: if all your inputs really have the same format then there is no problem. It's usually done when comparing dates with YYYY-MM-DD format. You probably would face problems if you did not write leading 0s though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use date_create_from_format you can specify the exact date format for php to convert the string representations to:

```
<?php
$input1 = '00:02:14.31';
$input2 = '00:02:14.32';
$novy = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u', $input1);
$stary = date_create_from_format('H:i:s.u',$input2);
if ($novy < $stary) {
    echo "1 shorter\n";
} else {
    echo "2 longer\n";
}
```

Recommended reading: https://www.php.net/datetime.createfromformat

Comment: i dont know why but i dont get not only hundreths but also seconds. here is var_dump of `$input2` `object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2014-02-21 00:02:14' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)`

Comment: True, you would. There's no mention that you didn't want seconds, and that the problem was that hundredths of seconds was being ignored - this solution addresses that problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some conditional logic to test if HH::MM::SS are identical, then simply compare XX, else use the strtotime() function that you are already using

Answer (score 0):

You are working with *durations*, not dates. PHP's date and time functions aren't really of any help here. You should parse the string yourself to get a fully numeric duration:

```
$time = '00:02:14.31';

sscanf($time, '%d:%d:%d.%d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds, $centiseconds);
$total = $centiseconds
       + $seconds * 100
       + $minutes * 60 * 100
       + $hours * 60 * 60 * 100;

var_dump($total);
```

The total is in centiseconds (100th of a second, the scale of your original input). Multiply/divide by other factors to get in others scales, as needed.